# Who was Esther’s mother?

Tags: esther--the-woman

The Megillah says the name of Esther’s father (Abichayel) but did anyone ever see a source naming her mother?

This isn’t a Halacha question but it would be nice to have a source for her mom’s name

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Just because it's not a halachic question doesn't mean it's not a good question.

Comment: Thank you. Someone asked this question a year ago and nobody has an answer yet. Today someone from a different neighborhood came and asked the original asker if he might know who Esther’s mother was. When a question comes full circle it might be time to widen the pool.

Comment: Do you mean her mother who died in childbirth or Mordechai's wife who nursed her and raised her? https://www.etzion.org.il/en/shiur-22-psalm-22-my-god-my-god-why-have-you-forsaken-me-complaint-supplication-and-thanksgiving . I don't know the answer but there are 2 possible people to research.

Comment: I suppose that it would be better to find her biological mother but either name should satisfy the question.

Comment: Does anyone have a possible name?